# Question on Administrative Unit in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a question on administrative units in Azure AD -

If someone has User Administrator Role scoped to their administrative unit, how do we add a new user?

The reason behind the query is that I've found that because the user is not yet in that unit, and administrator has no privileges to add new one the only option is to add to the User Administrator Role without administrative unit ( entire ad) - but I want to avoid that if possible.

Anyone has come across a similar situation? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted MS Support and got a reply that it's the expected behavior currently.

Adding a member into an administrative unit is an option relating to the entire tenant so it requires a directory role rather than a unit role.

But this feature is in preview and your requirement is reasonable. So it may be changed in the future.